# install ry2 on windows 7

Tags: rpy2

This is again a repetition of the same problem, but I was forced to put it as new question. So please donot delete this admins!

I am new to R and Rpy2. My problem is similar. I am using p*ython 2.6, R 2.15.1, rpy2 2.2.6, and Windows 7*.

**R_HOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1**

Typing "R" in the command prompt does not work.

**PATH: has these two--C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1**

**PYTHONPATH: C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib;C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\DLLs;C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\lib-tk**

When I run the setup.py I get "**error: no commands supplied**"!

I tried putting all file from bin/i386 to directly under bin.

My rinterface->init.py is different. However this is what I did:

```
# MSWindows-specific code
_win_ok = False
if sys.platform in _win_bindirs.keys():
    import win32api
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(R_HOME, 'lib')):             ## ADDED ##
        os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + os.path.join(R_HOME, 'bin')
        os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + os.path.join(R_HOME, 'modules')
        os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + os.path.join(R_HOME, 'lib')
        R_DLL_DIRS = ('bin', 'lib')
    else:                                   ## ADDED ##
        os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + os.path.join(R_HOME, 'bin', 'i386')     ## ADDED ##
        os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + os.path.join(R_HOME, 'modules', 'i386') ## ADDED ##
        os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + os.path.join(R_HOME, 'library')     ## ADDED ##
        R_DLL_DIRS = ('bin', 'library')


    # Load the R dll using the explicit path
    # Try dirs in R_DLL_DIRS
    for r_dir in R_DLL_DIRS:
        Rlib = os.path.join(R_HOME, r_dir, _win_bindirs[sys.platform], 'R.dll')
        if not os.path.exists(Rlib):
            continue
        win32api.LoadLibrary(Rlib)
        _win_ok = True
        break

    # Otherwise fail out!
    if not _win_ok:
        raise RuntimeError("Unable to locate R.dll within %s" % R_HOME)


# cleanup the namespace
del(os)
```

Nothing changes the setup.py error message. I am at my wits end. Please help!!

Avishek

Comment: `conda install rpy2` works perfectly in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Check the rpy mailing-list entries for the last week or so. There is a contributed binary built.